# Adding a comment for a blog post using UpdateView

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Assume I have a blog entry and the URL is `/blog/1` and now I want to comment on the blog post so I click on the url `/comment/1`. In Django, the `urls.py` will look something like

```
urlpatterns = (
  url(r'^blog/(?P<pk>[0-9])',BlogView.as_view())
  url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>[0-9])',CommentView.as_view()
)
```

and `models.py` is like

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_text = models.TextField()
    for_blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
```

So now I have a CommentForm in `forms.py`

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
  for_blog = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
  def __init__(self, blog, *args, **kwargs):
  .
  .
  class Meta:
    model=Comment
```

The question is, how do I implement this in a UpdateView in Django? In particular, I would like the `for_blog` in the CommentForm to be pre-populated with the `BlogID` so I can use it more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your actual question, to use the CommentForm, define the fields in the Meta class (you don't need anything else):

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:

    model=Comment
    fields = ['for_blog']
```

Then in your view, do something like:

```
class ClassView(UpdateView):

  def get(self, request, pk, ...):

    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk)
    forms = [CommentForm(instance=comment) for comment in blog.comment_set.all()]
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'forms': forms})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a formset (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/). Then you can use the pk to load the blog object, and pass that as the `instance kwarg` in the formset. Then just render the formset in the template and you'll have the associated blog comments.

Also allows an easy way to add more / remove comments and handy form management.